# How to avoid execution concatMap after throw error?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following a stream of click events:

```
this.createReestrClick
            .pipe(
                concatMap(() =>
                    this.documentsRepository.selectedDocumentsFilesIds$.pipe(
                        take(1),
                        tap((ids: number[]) => {
                            if (ids.length == 0) throw new Error('Error messsage!');
                        }),

                        indicate(this.createReestrloading$),
                        tap((ids: number[]) => (this.dialogConfig.data = { data: { ids }, width: '500px' })),
                        concatMap(() =>
                            this.dialog
                                .open(DialogDocumentCreateRegisterComponent, this.dialogConfig)
                                .afterClosed()
                                .pipe(
                                    filter(Boolean),
                                    concatMap((data: { date: Date; ids: number[] }) =>
                                        this.documentsRepository.CreateMailReestrById(data.ids, data.date),
                                    ),
                                    handleResponseMessage(this.messageService),
                                ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                catchError((e) => of(e)),
            )
            .subscribe((e) => {
                if (e instanceof Error) this.messageService.showMessage('', e.message, 'warning');
            });
```

Firts it listens clicks, then concat with `selectedDocumentsFilesIds$`. In case there are no values in array it throws an exeption:

```
if (ids.length == 0) throw new Error('Error messsage!');
```

First problem when in happend the inner stream `selectedDocumentsFilesIds$` does not work more. To solve this I have moved `catchError((e) => of(e)),` on the line:

```
tap((ids: number[]) => {
   if (ids.length == 0) throw new Error('Error messsage!');
 }),
catchError((e) => of(e))
```

In this case as I return an empty observer `of(e)` it allows to continue `concatMap(() =>`, but should not.

How to fix it, dont allow to execute `concatMap(() =>` if exception happens and dont stop steam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an abstract, you can do something like this

```
let hadError=false;
observable.pipe(
  ....
  yourThrowingErrorOperator(),
  catchError(err=> hadError=true),
  takeUntil(v=>hadError),
  concatMap(...)
.....
```

)

so once error will be cought in the upstream, downstream will be terminated. If you want to keep it up and running, use `filter` instead of `takeUntil` to "block" values in the stream while flag is set. Just remember to reset it somehow.

Comment: In your exampel I dont see `filter()`, so `catchError` needs only for inner?

Comment: catchError should return observer

Comment: I did this: `this.documentsRepository.selectedDocumentsFilesIds$.pipe(
                        take(1),
                        tap((ids: number[]) => {
                            if (ids.length == 0) {
                                this.messageService.showMessage('', 'Message', 'warning');
                                hadError = true;
                            }
                        }),
                        filter(() => !hadError),
                        indicate(this.createReestrloading$),`